# React App showing development build after Heroku deployment

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I recently deployed my react app on Heroku and when I visit my site it says "This page is using the development build of React. " How do I deploy the production version of my app? Do i have to modify something through Heroku or my React code? Below are my package.json scripts

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, did you read the documentation? Also, there are currently problems arising in the free use for Heroku since they are getting rid of the free version next month. Additionally, have you installed node too? Here is some help to go through -> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-deploy-react-app-to-heroku/